# Columns in LazyColumn stacked/collapsed into one

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

Columns in the `LazyColumn` get stacked into one.

Here is the code

```kotlin
package xxx.xxx.xxx

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class ActDevOnly : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                item {
                    Text("header")
                }
                items(5) { idx ->
                    Text("dummy title $idx")
                }
                item {
                    Text("footer")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the visual effect on a Nexus 6P(Android 8.1.0).

[image: visual effect]

Comment: Your code works fine to me(items arranged into a `Column`, not stacked), please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code [works completely fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxmfZ.png) for me as well.